# how to display google map route screen from your application?

Tags: android, google-maps

friends

i want to display this screen from my application of google map builtin application.
[image]

my function

```
String url = "http://maps.google.com/maps?f=d&hl=en&saddr=" + lat + ","
        + longi + "&daddr=" + bankDetail.getCoordinates() + "&dirflg=t";
        Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
        i.setData(Uri.parse(url));
        startActivity(i);
```

it show mentioned screen in emulator but not in phone.
any one guide me what mistake am i doing here?

Comment: Do you have google maps installed on your phone. It comes pre installed with every device but if you have installed any custom ROM for android than you may not have google maps installed on your phone.

Comment: check the Map key..for every user in your system Mapkey differs

Comment: google maps are built in and installed in phone.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

google only display that screen if route is not found. otherwise it displays that  route mentioned in parameter directly.(so it is not possible according to my research).

Answer (score 0):

I think you have update your Map Application in your device. If yes then it must be showing this screen [image]

So here on clicking the left icon you have all the different direction option and on clicking on right "M" icon you can see the route  on map.

Comment: what do you mean by i have updated map in your device i am using build in google map. yes i have installed another maps application too but when opening it i am using google map not that application.

Comment: Have you updated the default MAp application installed in your device ?